# how to properly format a v-for loop for multi-level array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm learning how the `v-for` loops work in Vue. Really liking the idea that I can run the loop directly in my template `HTML` but unsure how to properly use the v-for loop to delve into a multi level array.

I have variable called `playerDataList` it contains some JSON data. A sample of which is below

```
         "stats" : [ {
            "type" : {
            "displayName" : "yearByYear",
            "gameType" : null
            },
            "splits" : [ {
            "season" : "20052006",
            "stat" : {
                "assists" : 43,
                "goals" : 49,
                "pim" : 82,
                "games" : 62,
                "penaltyMinutes" : "82",
                "faceOffPct" : 0.0,
                "points" : 92
            },
            "team" : {
                "name" : "Lon. Jr. Knights",
                "link" : "/api/v1/teams/null"
            },
            "league" : {
                "name" : "Minor-ON",
                "link" : "/api/v1/league/null"
            },
            "sequenceNumber" : 1
            }, {
            "season" : "20062007",
            "stat" : {
                "assists" : 15,
                "goals" : 7,
                "pim" : 30,
                "games" : 62,
                "powerPlayGoals" : 0,
                "penaltyMinutes" : "30",
                "faceOffPct" : 0.0,
                "shortHandedGoals" : 0,
                "plusMinus" : 11,
                "points" : 22
            },
            "team" : {
                "id" : 1874,
                "name" : "Kitchener",
                "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1874"
            },
            "league" : {
                "id" : 141,
                "name" : "OHL",
                "link" : "/api/v1/league/141"
            },
            "sequenceNumber" : 1
            }, {
            "season" : "20072008",
            "stat" : {
                "assists" : 40,
                "goals" : 25,
                "pim" : 57,
                "games" : 68,
                "powerPlayGoals" : 10,
                "penaltyMinutes" : "57",
                "shortHandedGoals" : 0,
                "plusMinus" : 9,
                "points" : 65
            },
            "team" : {
                "id" : 1874,
                "name" : "Kitchener",
                "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1874"
            },
            "league" : {
                "id" : 141,
                "name" : "OHL",
                "link" : "/api/v1/league/141"
            },
            "sequenceNumber" : 1
            }
        }]
```

I've got this code so far, and it works to display my content, but it's only pulling me the first instance. It's not actually looping and giving me each occurrence.

```
         <div class="player-stats-card-inner">
            <p class="close" v-on:click='showPlayers = !showPlayers'>Close</p>
            <table>
              <th>
                <td>Goals</td>
                <td>Assists</td>
              </th>

              <!-- Loop through the JSON data -->
              <tr v-for="stats in playerDataList.stats" :key="stats.id">
                <td> 
                  {{stats.splits[0].stat.goals}}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{stats.splits[0].stat.assists}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>            
          </div>
```

Is there anything I could do differently to get this properly looping?

Comment: there is no `id` in the items, so use `v-for="(stats, index) in playerDataList.stats" :key="index"` then if you want to loop over splits, add another for loop and do `v-for="(stat, splits_index) in stats.splits" :key="splits_index"`, then its `{{stat.goals}}` etc.. just 2 basic loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop the inner properties of `stat`.  It is not an array.

```html
<tr v-for="stats in playerDataList.stats" :key="stats.id">
  <td v-for='(value, name) of stats.splits[0].stat'>
     {{name}} : {{value}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This will only give you the results from the first `season` in `splits`, which may or may not be what you need.

Comment: I made a quick tweak that solved for that. But this formatting was closest to what I needed! The required tweak taught me something along the way to. For anyone else who comes along the internal loop being set as `v-for="(value,name) of stats.splits" :key="name"`. I could then call items inside that loop like this `{{value.stat.goals}}`

Comment: because the season was hardcoded at `0`, i assumed the issue was iterating the stat properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 arrays to be iterated over, you need 2 `v-for` statements. Since you don't want 2 sets of `<tr>` elements, we use `<template>` which will not be rendered in the resulting HTML:

```
<!-- Loop through the JSON data -->
<template v-for="(stats, stats_index) in playerDataList.stats" :key="stats_index">
  <tr v-for="(split, split_index) in stats.splits :key="split_index">
    <td> 
      {{split.stat.goals}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{split.stat.assists}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

However since you are now displaying multiple goals and assists, you may need another 'level' in your table to identify which stat each one comes from.